# About the GraphQL query under React Relay

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I have 2 components with relay container, each container has a graphql query to fetch data. This two queries all fetch data from same table but different fields. The problem is if I write the fields what I need in each component it will not show any data when click the page link. If I write all fields in both of them then it will be working fine. So what can I do? is that means I can not one table twice? even in different component? Here is the part codes of relay container. Please help. Thanks! :)

```js
export default Relay.createContainer(ParcelDetails, {
  initialVariables: {
    tracking_number: null,
  },

  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        parcels(tracking_number: $tracking_number, first: 9999) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              tracking_number,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  },
});
```

```js
export default Relay.createContainer(LongOrderList, {
  
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        parcels(first: 99999) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              status,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  },
});
```

Comment: "it will not show any data when click the page link" I dont understand what you saying here. What page link? What click?

Comment: So you're saying that the second query doesn't return anything?

Comment: @NaotoIda Yes, that's right. the second query always doesn't return anything.

Comment: @LordDave  Thank you for your asking. I have a nav bar. one button is to show all parcels list, and one button is to show all the parcels list which processing longer than 7 days. but they may show some different parcel info. When the graphql queries with different fields. I click all parcels button it will show the list. after that if I click the other button will no data list.